# Hamming graphs and power series

Tags: graph-theory, power-series, coding-theory

Let $i$ and $h$ be two *adjacent* nodes in a Hamming graph and let $a$ be any positive real. Let us denote by $d_{ij}$ the distance between node $i$ and node $j$ in the graph. 
I'm trying to find a compact formula for the following (finite) power series, where $j$ runs over all nodes of the graph:

$$ S= \sum_j a^{d_{ij}+d_{hj} }. \tag{1}$$

Is this a studied problem?

If the graph is an $n$-hypercube, which is the case I'm most interested in, it seems that

$$ S =  \sum_{d=0}^n {{n-1}\choose {d}}a^{2d+1} +  {{n-1}\choose {d-1}}a^{2d-1}\tag{2}$$

In fact, if you fix node $i$ and consider all the nodes at distance $d$ from $i$, ${{n-1}\choose {d}}$  of them are at distance $d+1$ from $h$, while the remaining ${{n-1}\choose {d-1}}$ are at distance $d-1$. However, I fail to see now how (2) can be further simplified.

I would appreciate any reference to this problem.

Thank you,
M.

Comment: For the hypercube case S/a should simplify to 2(1+a^2)^(n-1).  Gerhard "Warning: Calculation Performed Sans Coffee" Paseman, 2012.01.27

Answer (score 1):

For the general case of bipartite graphs and adjacent vetices i and j, the graph partitions into sets I and J where I are those vertices closer to i than to j and vice versa. The desired sum is then (a+1) times the sum over I of weighted distances from i   plus (a+1) times a similar sum involving j and J.  Now you have to use some nice properties of I and J to get a nice form for the total.

Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman,  2012.01.27

Comment: Many thanks. I wonder what kind of properties one could invoke here. Some form of distance-regularity?

Comment: Play with it.  For starters, take a complete bipartite graph K_n,m and remove all edges from j except the one connecting to i. After looking at that, start adding edges one at a time to j, and see what you get.  Good luck.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2012.01.27

Comment: A comment on the more general case: one can parition an arbitrary connected graph into sets I, J and K, and sum over each siet for a given i and j.  I'll let professionals such as Brendan McKay tell you how much further you can run with such a set up.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2012.01.27

Answer (score 1):

As Gerhard points out, when the graph comes from a hyper-cube with $2^n$ points the sum is $2a(a^2+1)^{n-1}.$ When it comes from a Hamming graph with $s^n$ points the sum is $$(a(s-2)+2)a(a^2(s-1)+1)^{n-1}.$$